# Ruby - How to access elements in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I thought this was simple, but when it came down to this case I wasn't able to do it. I feel if I can understand this I will have a much better understanding of Ruby.

**WHAT**: I want to search inside a 2-d array of strings and integers, and return the index/indices of where a certain string is found. These indices of each subarray would also be placed in an array in the order of the corresponding subarrays.

Example when searching for the string "a":

***Input array:*** [[1,"a","a",3],[1,"b"],["a",2]]

***Output array:*** [[1,2],[],[0]]

**WHAT I TRIED**:
Intuitively I thought it would be something like:

```
source = [[1,"a","a",3],[1,"b"],["a",2]]
```

with

```
source.each.each_index.select { |v| v == "a" }
```

or

```
source.each {|x| x.each_index.select { |i| x[i] == "a" }}
```

**QUESTIONS**:

1) What should I call to get my output array from my input array?

2) I see so many other enumerators and methods get mashed together this way, how come I can't do it in this case? I don't want to clutter up this question with some of the simpler test cases I tried, but I either got undefined method errors or it would just return my source array.

3) Does it have to do with what blocks are associated with which methods? I modeled my code after the answer to question: [Find indices of elements that match a given condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659696/ruby-how-to-find-all-indices-of-elements-that-match-a-given-condition) where I am confused why it seems like the block is directly associated with multiple methods. In other words, the |i| is from the #each_index while the boolean is for the #select. Seems random and disorganized to me right now how to structure these blocks (i.e why not vice versa?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
source.map { |row| row.each_index.select { |i| row[i] == "a" } }
# => [[1, 2], [], [0]]
```

2. You can't do it because your logic is mistaken :) `source.each {...}` will return `source`, doesn't matter what you do inside the block. To return the result, use `map`. `source.each.each_index` calls `each_index` on the enumerator returned by `each` without block, and that's not a method available on enumerators (you want `each_index` on arrays).
3. Indeed. `each` with block and `each` without block will do very different things.

Specifically, in my code above:

Start with `source` array. `map` with block will process the block for each element (called `row`), and return an array of the results. For each row, `row.each_index` without block will return an iterator of all indices of the `row` array, `select` with block on the iterator will return an array that will contain only some of those elements.

Comment: Thanks! Oh so with you saying that "source.each {...} will return source", is it that even though the methods inside are returning things (e.g. #select), it will return the outermost (the most recently interpreted code) method which in this case is the #each which just returns the outer array (which is what I'm getting). However, it looks like even though #each would return itself, I can still print out the [1, 2], [], [0] result by calling source.each {|x| p x.each_index.select { |i| x[i] == "a" }}, it's just that it won't return it.

Comment: Also, since #each can be used on an enumerator (itself) it looks like I also have an option to call a .each.each and parse through to define my desired array, but it probably would be very verbose and inefficient compared to your solution.