# Find all indexes of maximum elements in array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
vals = [1,2,10,5,10,5,9,10]
```

I need the indexes of the largest element in the array (in the above example `10`).  So in my example, it should spit out another array:

`[2, 4, 7]`

However, when I use `#find_index` with a block, I can only get the first index it matches:

```
[12] pry(main)> vals.find_index { |i| i == vals.max }
=> 2
```

I can get what I want by doing this but it seems somewhat verbose:

```
[14] pry(main)> results = []
=> []
[15] pry(main)> vals.each_with_index do |elem, i|
[15] pry(main)*   results << i if elem == vals.max
[15] pry(main)* end
=> [1, 2, 10, 5, 10, 5, 9, 10]
[16] pry(main)> results
=> [2, 4, 7]
```

Does anyone have any ideas of a more ruby-like way to do this?

Comment: Calling `vals.max` for every element in your array is not a good plan. That has to spin through the array each time for each element, so you're O(N^2) there.

Comment: very good point @tadman - I can certainly store that value of max in it's own variable for comparison purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
vals = [1, 2, 10, 5, 10, 5, 9, 10]
max_val = vals.max

vals.each_index.select{|i| vals[i] == max_val}
```

<sub>*Note: answer derrived from [Find indices of elements that match a given condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659696/ruby-how-to-find-all-indices-of-elements-that-match-a-given-condition)*</sub>

Comment: ...but you would have thought of it anyway. Best way, imo.

Comment: I really like this - very Ruby!

Answer (score 3):

It's a little messy but you can do this:

```
vals = [ 1,2,10,5,10,5,9,10 ]
val_max = vals.max

result = vals.each_with_index.each_with_object([ ]) do |(v,i),a|
  a << i if (v == val_max)
end

# => [ 2, 4, 7 ]
```

Comment: Two alternatives, different by a hair: just `.with_object`, or `vals.each_with_object([ ]).with_index`, with block variables `|(v,a),i|`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Nice optimization.

Answer (score 3):

```
vals = [1, 2, 10, 5, 10, 5, 9, 10]
max = vals.max

vals.map.with_index {|n, i| i if n == max }.compact
# => [2, 4, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid two passes (i.e. one to get max_val, and then again to iterate over the list):

```
vals    = [ 1,2,10,5,10,5,9,10 ]
max_val = vals.first - 1
indices = []

vals.each_with_index do |n, idx|
  if n < max_val
    # Do nothing, but common case, so avoid second comparison
  elsif n == max_val
    indices << idx
  elsif n > max_val
    max_val = n
    indices = [ idx ]
  end
end

indices
```