# In Ruby, how do I return all the index value of elements in an array that have the same string values in them?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, calabash

How do I return all the index value of elements in an array that have the same string values in them?

For example:

```
myarray=[tree, bean, bean, bunny, frog, bean, soup]
```

If I searched for "bean" using something `myarray.index(bean)` it would return 1. If I did the same search using `myarray.rindex(bean)` it would return 5.

I need the method to `myarray.{does this method exist?}(bean)` that would return `[1, 2, 5]`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think I just found the solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659696/find-indices-of-elements-that-match-a-given-condition

Comment: A good question to ask is *why* you want to know that. Are you trying to remove duplicates? There's a bit of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) smell to the question.

Comment: What are the values of `tree`, `bean`, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#each_with_index` (create pair of string, index), then `#map` (iterate over the pairs and if it matches, then return index, otherwise return nil) and finally `#compact` (remove nil values) the array.

```
myarray.each_with_index.map{|x,i| x == "bean"? i : nil}.compact
```

Slightly simpler soulution and a better one also in terms of efficiency would be probably this one with `#each_index`.

```
 myarray.each_index.select{|x| myarray[x] == "bean"}
```

Btw. you should name the variable `my_array`, not `myarray`.

Comment: When using `map`, don't return nils in the block then use `compact`. That's wasting CPU and memory, especially for big arrays. You can accomplish the same thing by defining an empty array then using `each` and appending to an array inside the block then access the array except it won't waste CPU or memory.

Comment: thank Tin Man for the advise , you are totally right

Comment: I suggest `select` in place of `map`.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple & easy to understand solution given below**

```
myarray = [:tree, :bean, :bean, :bunny, :frog, :bean, :soup]

result = []
search_for = :bean

myarray.each_with_index() { |element, index| result << index if element == search_for }

p result
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 5]
```