# Selecting index from array based on value

Tags: arrays, ruby, select, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have Ruby code that looks like this:

```
  a = widgets["results"]["cols"].each_with_index.select do |v, i| 
    v["type"] == "string"
  end
```

I only want to get the index of any values where `v["type"]` is "string".  The outer array of "results" has about 10 values (the inner array of "cols" has two -- one of them having an index of "type"); I am expecting two results returned in an array like this: `[7, 8]`.  But, I am getting results like this:

```
[[{"element"=>"processed", "type"=>"string"}, 7], [{"element"=>"settled", "type"=>"string"}, 8]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659696/find-indices-of-elements-that-match-a-given-condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see `cols.each_with_index.to_a`:

```
[[{:element=>"processed", :type=>"string"}, 0], [{:element=>"processed", :type=>"number"}, 1], ...]
```

Would give you each hash in an array as the first value, and as the second one, the index. Difficult to get the index if select will *return an array that contains all elements of enum for which the given block returns true*.

But you also can try with `each_index`, which *passes the index of the element instead of the element itself*, so it would give you just the indexes, like `[0,1,2,4]`.

This way you could apply your validation accessing each element in the `cols` hash by its index and checking the value for the `type` key, like:

```
widgets = {
  results:  {
    cols: [
      { element: 'processed', type: 'string' },
      { element: 'processed', type: 'number' },
      { element: 'processed', type: 'string' } 
    ]
  }
}

cols = widgets[:results][:cols]
result = cols.each_index.select { |index| cols[index][:type] == 'string' }

p result
# [0, 2]
```

Comment: Note that there are alternatives to using [Array#each_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index), such as `result = cols.size.times.select { ... }`, `(0...cols.size).select { ... }` and `0.upto(cols.size-1).select { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use array inject method to get your expected output with minimal #no of lines and the code is something like below,

```
cols = [{'type' => 'string'}, {'type' => 'not_string'}, {'type' => 'string'}]
cols.each_with_index.inject([]) do |idxs, (v, i)|
  idxs << i if v['type'] == 'string'
  idxs
end
```

And the output is like below,

```
=> [0, 2]
```

You can change the code as per your need.